# Exporting DynamoDB document types to Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift

I have a DynamoDB table with some attributes which are [Document Types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes.Document): `list` and `map`, to be specific.

I'm trying to export these tables into Redshift. [According to the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Loading-data-from-dynamodb.html), the Redshift `copy` command will fail if you try to copy data from a DynamoDB table which includes either `list` or `map` attributes:

> Only Amazon DynamoDB attributes with scalar STRING and NUMBER data types are supported. The Amazon DynamoDB BINARY and SET data types are not supported. If a COPY command tries to load an attribute with an unsupported data type, the command will fail.

I've also investigated using a Data Pipeline and Hive, but [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMR_Interactive_Hive.html#EMR_Hive_Properties) suggests that Hive doesn't support `list` or `map` either.

What are the options for moving data out of a DynamoDB - including `list` and `map` attributes - and into Redshift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I've taken is to start with the [Export DynamoDB Table to S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-template-exportddbtos3.html) template.

The `org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.tools.DynamoDbExport` step which runs in the `EMRActivity` seems to output a manifest file specifically meant for use with the `RedshiftCopyActivity`: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/loading-data-files-using-manifest.html

So in addition to the `S3BackupLocation` data node which comes with the "Export DynamoDB Table to S3" template, I've added another `S3DataNode` which `dependsOn` the EMR activity. It specifies a `manifestFilePath`, which is the same as the `directoryPath` specified in the `S3BackupLocation` data node - except with `/manifest` added to the end.

That new data node - with the `manifestFilePath` - is then used as input for a `RedshiftCopyActivity`. To flatten attributes which are maps, the `RedshiftCopyActivity` specifies some `commandOptions` which provides [JSONPath options](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-format.html#copy-json-jsonpath-expressions):

```
"commandOptions": "JSON 's3://richard.jp.leguen/data-pipeline/misc/jsonpaths.txt'"
```